# I want to prevent copying file from memory card

Tags: software-design

I want to prevent my file to copy from any devices. Means that i have memory card and when i insert it in any device like android or computer than my file can't copy from that.

Any resources to read or any place that i can get some information about copy preventing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could partition the SD card and leave some space unpartitioned and write some magic bytes to it. When your program executes you'll determine the device the application ran from. If this is the SD card you'll try and read the raw bytes from the SD card and compare it with the magic bytes, if the program is not ran from SD card *or* if the magic bytes do not match it does not execute. Done!

Please don't get me wrong, this won't be easy, but maybe it could work. Copying would still work, but the file will be useless. Also, this is not a ready to made solution, but rather an outline how you could achieve your goal.

---

For accessing SD-Cards raw data please see
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28314/Reading-and-Writing-to-Raw-Disk-Sectors

And for partitioning http://geeks.lockergnome.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-partition-an-sd-card

Comment: What do you mean by magic bytes? Could you please explain or add some links?

Comment: The idea was to employ kind of a programmatic copy protection instead of preventing the file to be copied (basically, if you can read it, you can copy it). The program reads the raw sector on the card and if the data contained in the raw sector matches a predefined sequence of bytes (these are the magic bytes), the card is deemed the correct one and the program runs. See [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) - second definition.